# An odd text stops awk command from working

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I use `awk` command to count lines with same beginning...

For instance, in `try1.txt`, the texts are:

```
b : c
b : c
```

When I launch the following command in a terminal:

```
awk -F ' : ' '$1=="b"{a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) print "  ", i,a[i]}' try1.txt
```

it returns `c 2` which is good, because `b : c` appears twice in `try1.txt`.

The output of my tool is a huge `output.txt`, much more complicated than `try1.txt`. Some part of `output.txt` contains the following characters:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^137
```

It is systematically written by the system when a process is killed. I am OK with that. However, I realize that it stops `awk` from working well. For example, in `try2.txt` as follows:

```
b : c
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^137
b : c
```

The command `awk -F ' : ' '$1=="b"{a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) print "  ", i,a[i]}' try2.txt` returns `c 1`. That said, it stopped when it met the odd line `^@^@^@^@^@`.

I don't know how to keep the system from writing the odd line `^@^@^@^@^@`, so does anyone know how to amend `awk` command to workaround?

**Edit:** It seems that the `^@` I found in my `output.txt` is not normal characters `^@`. The following is a part of screen shot of `output.txt`, displayed in `Emacs`, which has trouble:

[image]

**Edit:** As suggested, I run `xxd try2.txt`, it gave:

```
0000000: 6220 3a20 630a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  b : c...........
0000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0031 3337 0a62 203a  .........137.b :
0000030: 2063 0a
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me. I think it is working because $1 will not match b in the offending line.

Comment: Which system are you working on? What version of awk?

Comment: Can you perform an `xxd` on the `^@` character to see what the hex code is?

Comment: Sorry, what is `xxd`?

Comment: It is a linux command to show the hexadecimal representation of a file, see http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xxd.htm

Comment: Yes you have null characters in your input file..

Comment: http://www.awk-scripting.de/cgi-bin/wiki.cgi/scripting/BinaryData

Comment: Try running strings filename pipe into awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^@` is likely a representation of a binary 0 / NUL character:

```
$ head -c10 /dev/zero > 10zero
$ cat -v 10zero 
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@$
```

Some text-oriented utilities may treat this as an end of file.

So since your input file is a binary file, you should have more luck extracting the text strings from it first and just operating on those:

```
$ strings try1.txt | awk -F ' : ' '$1=="b"{a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) print "  ", i,a[i]}'
   c 2
$
```

[The `strings` command man page.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings)  (btw watch out when you google "man strings" - you might get some images you might not have bargained for ;-) )

---

Note for the curious - I recreated the OP's try1.txt file exactly on my machine thus:

- capture the `xxd` output on the question to a text file called try1.xxd
- `xxd -r try1.xxd > try1.txt` [reverses the normal `xxd` operation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd).

Comment: Or just `tr -d '\000' <try1.txt | awk ...`

Answer (score 2):

Many Awk implementations, and Unix text-processing tools in general, handle null (zero) bytes poorly, because it is the string end terminator of the fundamental C libraries used to build these tools.

Perl was designed to work with arbitrary inputs; you can try `a2p` to convert your Awk script to Perl (but don't expect idiomatic, maintainable, or efficient Perl).

Or try this;

```
perl -lne '$a{$1}++ if (/^b : (.*?)\s*$/);  
    END { for $i (keys %a) { print " ", $i, " ", $a{$i} } }' try1.txt
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it returned two errors: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "m/^b : (.*?)\s*$/ { "` and `syntax error at -e line 1, near ";}"`

Answer (score 1):

If all of the lines you want contain a `:`, you can try putting `$0 ~ /:/` as a selector. Here's your *new and improved* awk statement (I wrote it on separate lines because it's easier for me to keep track of curly braces:

```
$ awk -F ' : ' '
{
    if ( $0 ~ /:/ && $1 == "b" )  {
    a[$2]++
    }
}
END {
    for (i in a) { 
    print "  ", i,a[i]
    }
}' try.txt
```

This worked as long as the `^@` were on their own line. If not, you have to find out what type of character `^@` is. I suspect it's a null character. If so, you may have to remove them from your file:

```
$ tr -d \0 < try.txt > try2.txt
```

This should remove those bothersome characters. Then, use `try2.txt` for input.